# Get Attachment Image Class by attachment id

Tags: attachments, images

I want Get wordpress media library image class.
I have attachment id and I tired this but won't able to get it.

```
print_r(wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size, $icon, $attr ));
```

How can I get it ?[image]

Comment: How do you create the box for classes, and where is it saved?

Comment: Never seen this field. Are you using some plugin that add it?

Comment: @toscho This is media file custom field.

Comment: https://github.com/glueckpress/flexslider-native-gallery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a regular custom field, use `get_post_meta()`:

```
$classes = get_post_meta( $attachment_id, 'name_of_the_field', TRUE );
```

`attachment` is just another post type, regarding to meta data, it works like regular posts or pages.

Comment: Here is the field <input type="text" class="text" id="attachments-28-classes" name="attachments[28][classes]" value="">

Comment: That’s just the name in the HTML form, it doesn’t tell you what name is used in the database. This is why I asked for that in my comment.